# Smote in R Error in `$<-.data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to use Smote in R.  I have been using imbalanced learn in python which has done well but now I need a code in R.  I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "trainClasses", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 500
Calls: $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

I follwed this guide: http://amunategui.github.io/smote/ but I am getting an error with the data.frame.  I believe this has to do with my ignorance with data structures in R.  If someone could kindly help me with my code, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
data = read.table("data.txt")
results10foldAll=c()

trainSet = as.data.frame(data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)])
trainClasses = as.factor(data[,ncol(data)])

trainSet$trainClasses <- as.factor(trainSet$trainClasses)
trainSet <- SMOTE(trainClasses ~ ., trainSet, perc.over = 100, perc.under=200)
trainSet$trainClasses <- as.numeric(trainSet$trainClasses)
```

Comment: Presumably `trainSet$trainClasses` is giving `NULL` since you created `trainClasses` as a vector in the Global Environment, not as a variable in `trainSet`.

Comment: does the "=" not work for variables.  Sorry I am new to R.  How can I correct this?

Comment: Not that is not an issue. My guess is to replace `trainClasses = as.factor(data[,ncol(data)])` by `trainSet$trainClasses = as.factor(data[,ncol(data)])`. But I can't check, since your example is not reproducible.

Comment: ok I am following you. That gets rid of the error but then I lose my labels "trainClasses".  After I have run smote I need the new data and labels.

Comment: Then don't overwrite it? Pick some new object name such as `trained <- SMOTE(......)`?

Comment: I see that my data shape changes.  I used a smaller set with 50 samples and it went from (50,989) to (4,989) when I print nrow and ncol

Comment: I think this has to deal with the prec.over and perc.under.  I don't understand why this would not update the new data shape inside of smote.  I have 40 classes, is there not a more efficient way to do this?